# Sort the values of lists corresponding to a row of excel numbers in a dictionary in descending order using openpyxl

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, openpyxl

**I currently have a task to sort the values of a list corresponding to a row of excel numbers in descending order and store them in a dictionary.**

For example I have an excel file like this:

0.296178       0.434362    0.033033    0.758968

0.559323       0.455792    0.770423    0.770423

I have created a dictionary using the code below to store the value of each cell as a list, with the key for each row being the row number.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import operator

vWB = load_workbook(filename="voting.xlsx")
vSheet = vWB.active

# Creating the Dictionary of agents and their alternative values
dictionary = {
    i + 1: [cell.value for cell in row[0:]]
    for i, row in enumerate(vSheet.rows)
}
```

output:

{1: [0.296177589742431, 0.434362232763003, 0.0330331941352554, 0.758968208500514], 2: [0.559322784244604, 0.455791535747786, 0.770423104229537, 0.770423104229537]....etc }

**However, I'm unsure how to order the values of each list in descending order without changing the order of the keys too.**

What I want:

{1: [0.758968208500514, 0.434362232763003, 0.296177589742431, 0.0330331941352554, 0.758968208500514], 2: [0.770423104229537, 0.770423104229537, 0.559322784244604, 0.455791535747786]....etc }

**How do I sort the list of values for each key in descending order?**

Comment: You should really update your original question and simply sort each row as you add it.

Comment: Sorry how do I update original question this is the first time I've used this site before.

Comment: Just use the edit function.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
d = {1: [0.758968208500514, 0.434362232763003, 0.296177589742431, 0.0330331941352554, 0.758968208500514],
 2: [0.770423104229537, 0.770423104229537, 0.559322784244604, 0.455791535747786]}

for key, value in d.items():
    print(sorted(value,reverse=True))
```

output
`[0.758968208500514, 0.758968208500514, 0.434362232763003, 0.296177589742431, 0.0330331941352554] [0.770423104229537, 0.770423104229537, 0.559322784244604, 0.455791535747786]`

Comment: Is there a way to update the dictionary order too using this. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by dictionary order ? what to replace the first key value with second?